# NullPointerException in Grails unit tests because of null Params and Session

Tags: unit-testing, grails

When migrating from Grails 2.0.0 to 2.1.2 some of our tests started failing with NullPointerException (the same behavior is observed with Grails 2.0.3)

Here are **snippets of code enough to reproduce the issue**.

The **controller**:

```
class TestController {

  def test() {
      render(template: "/test")
  }
}
```

The **unit test**:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.support.*
import org.junit.*
import grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin

@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(TestController)
class TestControllerTests {

    void test_paramsAndSession_Null() {
       controller.test()
       def result = response.text
       print result
       assert render(template: "/test") == result
    }
}
```

The **template** _test.gsp:

```
Params and session test.
Params(<%params.id1%>)<br/>
Session(<%session.id2%>)<br/>
```

With Grails 2.0.0 the application and the test work fine.

With Grails 2.1.2 the application still works fine, but the test starts failing with NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id1' on null object
at D__Eclipse_Workspace_paramsAndSessionTest_grails_app_views__test_gsp.run(_test.gsp:2)
at TestController.test(TestController.groovy:4)
at TestControllerTests.test_paramsAndSession_Null(TestControllerTests.groovy:12)

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id2' on null object
at D__Eclipse_Workspace_paramsAndSessionTest_grails_app_views__test_gsp.run(_test.gsp:3)
at TestController.test(TestController.groovy:4)
at TestControllerTests.test_paramsAndSession_Null(TestControllerTests.groovy:12)
```

(The second exception appears when fix (1) below is applied)

What is the reason for that?

I see I can fix the test making the following changes:

```
params.id1 -> params?.id1 (1)
session.id2 -> session?.id2
```

But this does not look like a valid solution (changing my application for unit tests to work).

Please help me understand whether I am doing something wrong or there is a bug in Grails.

**UPDATE**: I've submitted a bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9718

Comment: The error you get is due to the fact that you're assuming the presence of a id1 param and an id2 session key. The NPE is the (right) consequence of their absence, ihmo. So, if you're sure that those data will be always present and your test is not checking their values, then you should set them in the test. What's the goal of your test?

Comment: Thanks for submitting the bug.
I experience the same problem even if I manually set the special params object in my unit test.